# SQL Server - how to use derived table for calculated field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to use a calculated field value in a WHERE clause in my query, and after some research I know I need to create a derived table.  I'm not sure the syntax however, since my calculated field uses a CASE statement like:

```
        CASE T.IsReassigned
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                    (SELECT top 1 SXAVWFTaskHistory.CreatedWhenUTC from SXAVWFTaskHistory where TaskID = T.TaskID and StatusID = 7 order by TaskHistoryID desc),
                    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())                        
        ELSE 
        CASE Stat.StatusID      
            WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now 
            WHEN 2 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, TH.CreatedWhenUTC) 
        END 
    END as TaskItemAge,
```

I want to then use the TaskItemAge value in the where clause something like:

```
WHERE TaskItemAge > @TaskAgeStart AND TaskItemAge < @TaskAgeEnd
```

How do I put that CASE statement into a sub-select?

********************** *EDIT* ********************
Sorry, I'm still a bit confused as to how this would work.  Here's a larger snippet of my query:

```
    SELECT TSK.TaskID, --0
    TH.IsLatest,
    TH.CreatedWhenUTC as TaskHistoryCreationDate, --10
    TS.Name AS STATE,
    CASE T.IsReassigned
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                    (SELECT top 1 SXAVWFTaskHistory.CreatedWhenUTC from SXAVWFTaskHistory where TaskID = T.TaskID and StatusID = 7 order by TaskHistoryID desc),
                    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())                        
        ELSE 
        CASE Stat.StatusID      
            WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now 
            WHEN 2 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, TH.CreatedWhenUTC) 
        END 
    END as TaskItemAge,
    ctx.ContextTypeName,  
    ctx.ContextDescription, --15
    TH.TouchedWhenUTC as TaskHistoryModifiedDate
INTO #ii        
FROM SXAVWFTask TSK 
INNER JOIN SXAVWFTaskHistory TH ON TSK.TaskID = TH.TaskID
INNER JOIN @PagedTemp T on TH.TaskHistoryID = T.TaskHistoryID

Where TaskItemAge > @TaskAgeStart AND TaskItemAge < @TaskAgeEnd
```

Comment: A *Derived Table* is just any set of rows generated by (i.e., derived from) a SELECT statement.  In SQL Server derived tables that can also be used in queries include 1) Sub-Queries, 2) CTEs, and 3) Views.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  case ... end as CaseColumn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   CaseColumn between 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Andomar's is the correct form (+1), here is your specific syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CASE T.IsReassigned
            WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                        (SELECT top 1 SXAVWFTaskHistory.CreatedWhenUTC from SXAVWFTaskHistory where TaskID = T.TaskID and StatusID = 7 order by TaskHistoryID desc),
                        SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())                        
            ELSE 
            CASE Stat.StatusID      
                WHEN 1 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now 
                WHEN 2 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())    -- time duration between when task is created(use SXAVWFTask.CreatedWhenUTC) and now
                ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TSK.CreatedWhenUTC, TH.CreatedWhenUTC) 
            END 
        END as TaskItemAge
    FROM BaseTable
) as DerivedTable
WHERE TaskItemAge > @TaskAgeStart AND TaskItemAge < @TaskAgeEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
  ;WITH cte AS
   (
    SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS TaskItemAge
    FROM your_table
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE TaskItemAge > @TaskAgeStart AND TaskItemAge < @TaskAgeEnd
```

Comment: I upvoted, but my own opinion is that if you are only going to use the subquery once, using cte is overengineering.